# Calculating power losses in a wire based on frequency

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, litz-wire, losses

It's been years since college, and I'm drawing a blank on this: If I use a 12AWG wire (say a 0.083" diameter bundle of .0125" uninsulated strands) to conduct power at 25kHz to a device, how would I calculate the power loss in the wire?

I understand skin effect, and I do know that as long as the OD of the wire can carry the current, the losses will be less, but can't seem to find the formula for calculating the non-litz power loss or efficiency of the wire as a power conductor.

Comment: https://myelectrical.com/notes/entryid/113/the-ac-resistance-of-conductors

Comment: See: http://inductor.thayerschool.org/papers/stranded.pdf https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/581768/stranded-wire-resistance-compared-to-solid-wire https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/635417/is-there-a-simple-method-to-estimate-the-copper-loss-of-litz-wire

Comment: The skin frequency of 12AWG is 4150Hz, not enough of a factor at 25Hz to worry about. You can expect about 5.20864 Ohms per kilometer on 12AWG copper.

Comment: @dandavis - I'm working at 25kHz, not 25Hz and I'm moving a lot of power.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that since the strands are not insulated (not Litz wire) you can treat it as a solid conductor of the same cross section. Then if you figure out the skin depth you can calculate the "cross section" at that frequency. Since that is X times smaller than the real cross section, the wire would have X times bigger resistance at that frequency than at DC.